# Wikipedia: "Newer forms of web scraping involve listening to data feeds from web servers" . What does that mean?

Tags: web-scraping, websocket, server, serversocket

On the [Web Scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) page on Wikipedia, it's written:

> Newer forms of web scraping involve listening to data feeds from web servers.

What does that mean?

Which technologies / frameworks are involved in doing this?

Comment: Lots of web pages are not just static HTML, they use secondary channels (Server Pushes, AJAX/WebSockets, etc) to download live data from servers and update page content dynamically without having to perform whole page refreshes.  Sometimes that same data is available via other types of feeds (RSS, REST, etc) that are made available for non-web applications to access.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ! I know there are a lot of contents to learn how to do classic scraping with python (books, moocs...) but I don't know where I can learn Server Pushes, AJAX/WebSockets scraping. Do you know where I can learn thoses kind of scraping ?

Comment: I think you missed my point. In "classic" scraping, you download and parse an HTML webpage, which is designed for *human* consumption. AJAX/WebSockets/etc doesn't change that, only how the webpage itself gets its data before you download it. Basically, you are just pretending to be a web browser and a human for purposes of extracting data. Whereas in REST/etc, the same data may be offered in a more structured format that is designed for *application* consumption (XML, JSON, etc), so there is no pretending involved.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. If I use scrapy, Im "listening to data feeds from web servers" ? Same thing if Im using an headless navigator ?